# IOS CollectionView with UIImage load from url

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uicollectionview

I have an UICollectionView and I want to load picture from web to the UIImageView which on cell. (The UIImageView with tag:100 on the cell.)

The picture isn't appear when I use this method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Img = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://192.168.1.103:8088/Images/1.png",@"http://192.168.1.103:8088/Images/2.png",nil];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *identifier = @"List";  
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *chImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[Img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];
    chlImage.image = image;

    NSLog("%@",[Img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); //Here can show Img's values correctly 

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroung.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

But when I use the picture in project, it can appear correctly. like this:

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *identifier = @"List";  
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *chImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100]; 
    chImage.image = [UIImages imageNames:@"123.jpg"];

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroung.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Why it can't work when I used picture load from web? (The picture can be opened by "browser".)

Can give me some tips or correct code?   Thank you very much!

Comment: can you see the images if you just type those URLs into Safari?

Comment: your Img array will be recreated each time through your method... but it says NSArray not NSArray*... is this the actual code?

Comment: Sorry, the actual code: NSArray "Img" is putted in Viewdidload and it use point like  NSArray* Img =.....

Comment: You should not use [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:] to fetch images over the network since it's  synchronous. It will block your UI interactions. However, It you set a breakpoint on that row, does the app load the actual image?

Comment: If I don't use [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL], are there any method to load image from web?

Comment: Your method reaches it's end before it gets a chance to download the image from the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expecting to get an UIImageView from this line:

```
UIImageView *chImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
```

But you are not. You are getting just an `UIView`. So you must create an `UIImageView` and then use `addSubview:` method to add this `UIImageView` to the `backgroudView`View.

So, it should be:

```
UIImageView *chImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.backgroundView.frame.size.width,cell.backgroundView.frame.size.height)];

NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[Img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];
chImage.image = image;

NSLog("%@",[Img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); //Here can show Img's values correctly 

[cell.backgroundView addSubview:chImage];
```

And finally, I have a suggestion for you. Take a look at [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library. It's an awesome feature to fetch images from URL.

Comment: I used imageView with tag:100 on the cell.
When I use the picture in project, it can appear correctly. like this:

    UIImageView *chImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    chImage.image = [UIImages imageNames:@"123.jpg"]
Why it can't work when I used picture load from web?

Comment: I'm not sure why, I've never used DataWithContents to fetch images from web because it's not recommended since it's syncronous. Try this library instead: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 2):

Create a class ImageCell by subclassing UICollectioViewCell and create a property ImageCell.h:

```
@interface ImageCell : UICollectionViewCell
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *dImage;
@end
```

Then add a function in ImageCell.m

```
- (void)downloadImageFromURL:(NSURL *)imageUrl
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImageView *chImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
            chImageView.image = dImage;
        });
    });
}
```

Now from UICollectionView delegate:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"List";  
    ImageCell *cell = (ImageCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[Img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell downloadImageFromURL:imageUrl];

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

And at last please make sure that you set the tag 100 to that ImageView you are trying to get. Let me know if you have any confusions.

Comment: In ImageCell.m, cell is undeclared. So UIImageView *chImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100]  will exit error. And I copy the code which in downloadImageFromURL to the UICollectionView delegate, it isn't work. Can you give me more clear code? Thanks!

Comment: Do UIImageview *chImageView = [self viewWithTag:100]

Answer (score 1):

Simply move your data fetching part from the collection view's delegate to it's viewDidLoad.

Store the images into an array. And use this as the datasource for your collection view.

ie.Each time an image gets added to the array just reload the collection view.

Or you could create a custom cell that does this as 'iOSGeek' suggested.